# Redireccionar URL con WordPress, manteniendo la misma carpeta del artículo

Tags: wordpress, regex, redirección

Quiero crear una expresión regular para redireccionar de la URL:

```
www.dominio.moda/category/articulo-de-ejemplo
```

a:

```
www.dominio.moda/articulo-de-ejemplo/
```

---

Para hacerlo estoy poniendo:

- URL de origen: `/category/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)/$`
- URL de destino: `/$3`

Pero algo estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 1):

El `$3` que estás usando, se refiere al 3er grupo de paréntesis, que no existe en tu expresión, sino que lo arrastraste de donde lo hayas copiado.

En cambio, al utilizar 1 único grupo (un único par de paréntesis), el texto capturado estará en `$1`.

Regex:

```
^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$
```

Redireccionar a:

```
$1
```

Comment: Gracias Mariano, lo voy a probar